# Filtering array in d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to filter out an array using D3. I have nested it and taken an map of the keys from a csv file. I want to filter it to show the values that match any of those keys in the array but am getting blank whenever I check the console after filtering.

```
var id = d3.nest()
           .key(function(d) {return d.id})
           .map(rows);        
id = d3.keys(id);
id.filter(function(d){d==input})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a work around but I created a function to filter the array which works for me.

```
function contain_item(item){
  return(item == input);
}

id = id.filter(contain_item);
```

Comment: The callback in your question's snippet is missing the `return`, which is included in function `contain_item()`. This is not a work around, but the solution.